# sharing data between the directives angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive, directive, data-sharing, pass-data

I have a page with 2 directives. one directive(Directive-1) is responsible for loading data grid(using KENDO-GRID) and another directive has buttons to print, export as Excel, PDF files etc.

From Directive-2, when export button is clicked, I need to get an access to the kendo Grid DATA that is part of Directive-1

What is the best way to implement Export functionality of the kendo-GRID DATA, where both grid data and export functionality are written as seperate directives?

Questions:
 1. How do I share data from directive-1 to directive-2 for export?
 2. Should I grab the data from directive-1 and put it in Parent controller and then pass that data from parent controller to directive-2? if yes, what is the efficient way of doing it?
[issue Explanation as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efFO7.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please read the following post before posting a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Give some examples of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines and i have edited my question.